# JSDoc not recognizing child of node module

Tags: node.js, parameters, require, node-modules, jsdoc

So I'm writing a Node.js application and I'm using JSDocs and a node module called botbuilder.

There's a class **Session** inside botbuilder that I would like to use in my documentation so it is clear that **myFunction** must take a parameter of type **Session**.

For example:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var Session = require('botbuilder').Session;

/**
 * @param {Session} session
 * @param {*} args
 */
exports.myFunction = function (session, args) {

}
```

As is hopefully clear I'm writing two require() statements which I feel like I really should only be writing one.

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

/**
 * @param {builder.Session} session
 * @param {*} args
 */
exports.myFunction = function (session, args) {

}
```

I've researched for hours now but no joy so I wanted to ask if anyone knew how this could be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure but have you tried `var Session = builder.Session;` and `@param {Session} session` ?

Comment: Yep I've tried that, but thanks for offering a suggestion.